# How to add one more class attributes to already exiting link_to in HAML

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

```
  = link_to 'AdWords Info', admin_settings_adwords_path, :class => ('active' if params[:action] == 'adwords')
```

class to add- :class => “links1"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just concatenate the two classes into a single one

```
= link_to 'AdWords Info', admin_settings_adwords_path, :class => (params[:action] == 'adwords' ? 'links1 active' : 'link1')
```

or, to have it a bit cleaner, do it in two steps

```
- adwords_class = (params[:action] == 'adwords' ? 'links1 active' : 'link1')
= link_to 'AdWords Info', admin_settings_adwords_path, :class => adwords_class
```

Of course, purist will insist that you shouldn't do this in a view, and they are right.
You should set `adwords_class` in the controller, as an instance variable.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to do this heavily view related assignment in the view itself. The class key can also use an array as value. So one could also write `- adwords_class = [: links1] + params[:action] == 'adwords' ? [:active] : []`